# How to Display RecordsAffected from Query in Msgbox

Tags: ms-access

I have a button on an MS Access form that is copying records from a table to an archive table.  I have the warnings set to false, but would like to display the count of records inserted into that archive table to the enduser.  I have tried a bunch of variations of code that I've found online, but everything returns a count of 0, even though the records are appending.  I am using Access 2013. Below is my current code. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub cmdArchiveReceipts_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim RowsInserted As String


On Error GoTo Err_cmdArchiveReceipts_Click

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

db.QueryDefs("qryAppend_to_Receipts_Archive").Execute
RowInserted = db.recordsAffected
MsgBox RowInserted & " Appended"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True


Exit_cmdArchiveReceipts_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdArchiveReceipts_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdArchiveReceipts_Click


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.Execute` on a query rather than executing a SQL string for the database (i.e. `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO..."`), you need to also use `.RecordsAffected` against the query itself:

```
db.QueryDefs("qryAppend_to_Receipts_Archive").Execute
RowInserted = db.QueryDefs("qryAppend_to_Receipts_Archive").RecordsAffected
```

Regards,

Comment: You are absolutely my hero!  Thank you so much.  I do have a follow up question.  It won't be an issue in this case, but just for my future knowledge.  Does the db.QueryDefs("qryAppend_to_Receipts_Archive").RecordsAffected contain the actual number of rows inserted.  For example if there is a index violation that prevents 10 of the 32 rows from appending, will the RowsAffected contain the correct number of 22?  Thanks again for all your help.  You've saved me.

Comment: It appears that this only counts records that have been successfully added.

Comment: WONDERFUL!!  Thanks again.